# Perl nested hash of dependency for programs

Tags: perl

I need create hash of dependency in Perl. The program1 depends from program2 program4 program10 program5 program7 program6 etc. Data are randomly generated for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

my $dependsOrder = {};
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $component, $depends ) = split /:/, $line;
    if ( exists $dependsOrder->{$component} and $dependsOrder->{$component} == 1 ) {
        $dependsOrder->{$component} = {};
    }
    if ( $depends ) {
        $depends =~ s/^\s+|\s+$// if $depends;
        my @depends = split /\s+/, $depends;
        for my $dependency ( @depends ) {
            if ( not exists $dependsOrder->{$dependency} ) {
                # default value
                $dependsOrder->{$dependency} = 1;
            }
            $dependsOrder->{$component}->{$dependency} = $dependsOrder->{$dependency};
        }
    }
    else {
        $dependsOrder->{$component} = 1;
    }
}
print Dumper $dependsOrder->{'program1'};
#print Dumper $dependsOrder->{'program6'};

__DATA__
program1: program2 program4 program10 program5 program7 program6
program2: program7 program5 program9 program8 program10 program3 program6 program1
program3: program2 program9 program8
program4: program5 program8 program10 program1 program2 program2 program9
program5: program3 program6 program4 program7
program6: program5 program8 program7
program7: program1 program2 program9 program10
program8: program1 program9 program6 program10 program3 program2 
program9: 
program10: program6 program9
```

This code not really works:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'program7' => 1,
          'program10' => 1,
          'program6' => 1,
          'program2' => 1,
          'program4' => 1,
          'program5' => 1
        };
```

But if I change the 22nd line:

```
$dependsOrder->{$dependency} = 1;
```

with:

```
$dependsOrder->{$dependency} = {};
```

It works fine, but I do not have a default value:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'program7' => {
                          'program2' => {
                                          'program8' => {
                                                          'program9' => {},
                                                          'program6' => {
```

What is wrong in my reasoning with default values?

Comment: What does `1` mean? Why do you want a default value of 1?

Comment: What do you expect to do if there is a circular dependency? Your example has one (p1 -> p4 -> p1)

Comment: This was only an idea. I need dependency tree for sorting an array of programs.
And this was wrong bad example. In fact I do not have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the data to the following allows the problem to be examined more effectively:

```
program1: program2
program2: program7
```

---

In the first case, what you do boils down to

```
$d->{p2} = 1;
$d->{p1}{p2} = $d->{p2};     # $d->{p1}{p2} = 1;
$d->{p2} = {};
$d->{p7} = 1;
$d->{p2}{p7} = $d->{p7};     # $d->{p2}{p7} = 1;
```

`$d->{p1}{p2}` contains `1`, and `$d->{p2}` contains a reference to a hash which is modified in the last line.

---

In the second case, what you do boils down to

```
$d->{p2} = {};
$d->{p1}{p2} = $d->{p2};
$d->{p7} = {};
$d->{p2}{p7} = $d->{p7};
```

`$d->{p1}{p2}` and `$d->{p2}` contain references to the same hash, which is modified in the last line.

---

Your code could have been written as follows:

```
my %dependency_tree;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ( $component, $depends ) = split /:/;
    $dependency_tree{$component} ||= {};
    for my $dependency (split ' ', $depends) {
        $dependency_tree{$component}{$dependency} =
            $dependency_tree{$dependency} ||= {};
    }
}
```